# MomentJS round date to the next valid one

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a variable X that is a Number from 1 to 31, and a routine that checks if today is X/CURRENT-MONTH/CURRENT-YEAR. The problem is if the user inputs a number that is not a valid date for the current month, let's say 31, so the date would turn up as 31/06/2020.

I quickly researched the MomentJS docs and didn't see any native function that could "round up" the day until it finds a valid date. My current solution is something like this:

```
let x = 31;
let validDate = moment(x + '/06/2020');

while(!validDate.isValid()) {
    x = getNextDayOfMonth(x); // in case of 31, would return 1;
    validDate = moment(x + '/06/2020');
}
```

Is there any better approach than that? Feels really hacky for something that should be simpler, at least on my point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `add` api is what you'are looking for:

```js
moment('06/30/2020').add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD') // "2020-07-01"
moment('12/31/2020').add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD') // "2021-01-01"
```

edit:
You should check the date number and subtract by one and then `add` one day:

```js
if (dateNumber > 1) {
  dateNumber -= 1
}

moment(`${dateNumber}/06/2020`, 'DD/MM/YYYY).add(1, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work with invalid dates: `moment('31/06/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY').add(1, 'd')` results in "Invalid date"

Comment: @FelipeWagner The date format is MONTH/DATES/YEAR, I also got `invalid date` the first time I tried, after I figured out the correct position, it works as I showed above

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work the way I did (passing the format parameter). Thank you sir.

Comment: @FelipeWagner Ok, I should have told you to check the date number if is bigger than one, if true, you subtract one from the number and perform the `add` function to let moment calculate a valid date